# In-Memory single-table database algorithm or library

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Starting with the problem I'm trying to solve:

- Given a single flat table-like structure (rows and columns)
  with smallish sized data (less than 50,000 rows)
- I need to rapidly find matching rows given an array of column indexes
  using exact equality matching. (Typically 2-3 columns will be
  involved with with a given query)
- Up to 1000 queries against the data that all have to complete within 
  1 second
- Data can be appended to or updated asynchronously in batches that
  will kick off the queries again
- Queries can (and ideally should) run in parallel
- Data is immutable while queries are being run
- Java based

I looked at some in-memory databases like H2 and VoltDB, but the SQL overhead dominated the search, even with PreparedStatements.  Full table-scans of immutable Object[][] works up to a point, but leaves a lot of optimizations off the table (like indexes).  If I start building indexes and marge-sets, it feels like I am re-inventing the database.

Any recommendations for an existing open-source library or datastructure that can handle this?  Or am I better off continuing my "invented here" approach and start rolling my own indexes?  For my "invented here" approach, I'm using Object[][] for the data and coding it like (up to 1000x in parallel using Akka):

```
public int[] findMatchingRows(int[] columnIndex, Object[] columnValues){
   List<Integer> matchingRows = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for(int row=0;i<data.length; row++){
     boolean found = true;
     for(int colIdx=0;j<columnIndex;colIdx++){
         if(!matches(data[row][columnIndex[colIdx], columnValues[colIdx]){
            found = false;
            break;
         }
     }
     if(found){
       matchingRows.add(row);
     }
   }
   return matchingRows;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like H2, Derby or some other in memory DB are the best choice. Just make sure you create indexes correctly. The alternative would be to have one `TreeMap` or even `HashMap` per column so you can search given values, but the complexity might be overkill and the cost of maintaining and understanding the code might be too high compared to the slight performance you would gain.

Answer (score 0):

A simple hand-rolled approach is to, for each "indexed" column, put all the rows into a `HashMap<ColumnType, HashSet<Row>>`, so that each distinct key value maps to a list of all rows having that key value in that column. A query can be executed by getting all the `HashSet<Row>` for the key values in the query, and taking their intersection.

The expected time complexity for this will be *O(km)*, where *k* is the number of keys in the query and *m* is the maximal number of hits from any key column.